# DbUpdateConcurrencyException on insert

Tags: entity-framework

I am inserting data into a table for an integration test using Entity Framework 6. When I execute the following code, I get a DbUpdateConcurrencyException on the call to SaveChanges().

```
using (var context = new CONTACTEntities())
{
    context.Facilities.AddRange(facilities);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. The table should be empty since the tables are dropped/created before the test runs and this is the only place in the test that I insert any data into this table. Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see the code to construct facilities, and the data model?

Comment: Really strange because Cuncurrency exception is raised only on SQL Server UPDATE and DELETE. How do you fill facilities? Also, turn on the SQL Server Profiler to see the UPDATE/DELETE statement that raises the Exception.

Comment: I had this situation with a `datetime2(7)` column that was marked as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` when really it needed to be `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQLServer and you have a datetime column in your table, change the columns type to datetime2(7).

It sounds strange but it works. The explanation is something about milliseconds.

You must be aware of how Entity Framework handle keys in your table. In my code I set the HasDatabaseGeneratedOption. It can be otherwise in your code.

```
 public class IceCatCategoryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<IceCatCategory>
 {
    public IceCatCategoryMap()
    {
        ToTable("SemlerServices_IceCatCategory");
        HasKey(m => m.Id);
        Property(m => m.Id).IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    }
}
```